# Posting message use toast and setText() inside thread

Tags: android

i want to post some message with setText() method inside thread when readline!= null, but i found error. I can't show toast and use setText() method.

```
public void run(){

    Looper.myLooper();
    Looper.prepare();

    try {           
        while(!((line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))){              
            if(line.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("there is no message");
            }else{                      

     Toast.makeText(this, "Message= " + line , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                msgbox.setText(line);
            }               
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Gagal mengirim ACK ke server");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your error?

can this code solve it?

```
    try {       

            final StringBuffer strMessage = new StringBuffer();

        while(!((line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))){              
            if(line.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("there is no message");
            }else{                      

            strMessage.append(line)

            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Message= " + line , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             msgbox.setText(strMessage.toString());
            //...
                    }
                });

            }               
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Gagal mengirim ACK ke server");
    }
```

runOnUiThread(...) Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

Comment: @breceiveemail: i got this error message : "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){}, String, int)"

Comment: use `Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, ...)`

Comment: put the real name of your Activity class instead of **YourActivity**

Comment: i write like this : 'public void run (){this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
..................}'but still failed.

Comment: did you change `Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Message= " + line , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` ?

Comment: yes i did, toast method is success but msgbox.setText() method still failed...@_@

Comment: i think because in "MyActivity" don't have method to read text...but how can i create that method on "MyActivity" and call it???

Comment: you have problem in `findViewById` i think

Comment: i don't think so, i've checked that

Answer (score 2):

You cannot show toast in any thread other than UI thread.. you can use a handler for that or runOnUiThread for this purpose..

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "Message= " + line , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            msgbox.setText(line);
}
});
```

Comment: i got error comment like this: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update your UI from a non main thread. You have either use [handlers and Threads](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Or simply try his, create a obj for Activity like this,

`Activity activityobj= yourActivity;` And use it inside your run(),

```
public void run(){

Looper.myLooper();
Looper.prepare();

try {           
    while(!((line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))){              
        if(line.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("there is no message");
        }else{                      
     activityObj.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
Toast.makeText(this, "Message= " + line ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            msgbox.setText(line);

        }
    });


        }               
    }           
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Gagal mengirim ACK ke server");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Create a Handler inside your class :

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Message= " + line ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        msgbox.setText(line);
    }
};
```

2) Modify your code like the follows :

```
public void run(){

Looper.myLooper();
Looper.prepare();

try {           
    while(!((line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))){              
        if(line.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("there is no message");
        }else{                      
           mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }               
    }           
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Gagal mengirim ACK ke server");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
Handler handler = new Handler();    
public void run(){
Looper.myLooper();
Looper.prepare();
try {           
    while(!((line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))){              
        if(line.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("there is no message");
        }else{                      
  handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(this, "Message= " + line , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            msgbox.setText(line);
                    }
                });


        }               
    }           
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Gagal mengirim ACK ke server");
}

}
```